# The tensor product of a line bundle with its dual $L\otimes L^*$ is isomorphic to the trivial line bundle

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, vector-bundles, line-bundles

Let $L$ be a holomorphic line bundle and $L^*$ be the dual holomorphic line bundle.

So I believe what we want to show is that  the following diagram commutes

[image]

(plus some condition on the restriction map on the fibers).

The "proof" I have seen just states to look the cocycles. I am not that familiar with cocycles, but I can make an attempt. Let $\phi_{ij}$ and $\psi_{ij }$ be the cocycles of $L$, $L^*$  respectfully and without proof I assume $\phi_{ij}\otimes \psi_{ij }$ is a cocycle of $L\otimes L^*$.

So $\phi_{ij}\otimes \psi_{ij }(x,v)\mapsto (x,g_{UV}\cdot g^*_{UV}(x)v)$

And this is where I get confused, Think somehow the transition maps $g_{UV}\cdot g^*_{UV}$ should give the identity but I not sure how it follows or if we should get the identity.

According to [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dual_bundle#Constructions_and_examples) we get that $g^*_{UV}$ is the inverse of the transpose of $g_{UV}$.

Comment: Since these are line bundles, you just multiply the $\Bbb C^*$-valued functions. And yes, the transition functions (cocycles) of the dual are the inverse in this case. You can see this and the result itself directly by considering the pairing (contraction) $L^*\otimes L$ to the trivial bundle. You can see directly that this is an isomorphism.

Comment: @TedShifrin I am sorry I can't quite follow your comment, this is all very new to me.

Comment: Can you prove that if $V$ is a $1$-dimensional complex vector space, then $V\otimes V^* \cong \Bbb C$?

Comment: (Don’t just use dimension. Try to make an argument that will generalize to the situation at hand.)